# MySQL индексы, не равно

Tags: mysql

При использовании не равно сервер проходит по всем записям, несмотря на то, что для data создан индекс

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `data` != '0'
```

Суть в том, что мне надо сделать запрос для выбора рандомных юзеров, но надо отфильтровать лишних (у которых нет авы, которые заблокированы и т.п.)

Comment: Какой тип у data?

Comment: один varchar и два int

SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(avatar)) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE `avatar` != '0' AND `group` != 3 AND `secrecy` != 3

Comment: @Fangog, ответьте, пожалуйста, на заданный вопрос. У поля не бывает трех типов одновременно.

Comment: Я про то, что в оригинальном запросе используется 3 поля

У data - varchar

Comment: а индексы у вас, надо полагать, на каждое поле созданы, а не на все одновременно?

Comment: >`FLOOR(COUNT(avatar)) AS count`

FLOOR??? количество может быть не целым? Псевдоним `count` не самое лучшее название, так как это слово является зарезервированным, лучше исправьте на `cnt`

Comment: На все одновременно. Я уже и так, и так пробовал

Comment: @Fangog, на sqlfiddle.com создайте пример, посмотрим. и правда интересно.

Comment: если по индексу не удается отсеять порядка 70%-85% записей, MySQL, как правило, считает предпочтительным полное сканирование (и это в большинстве случаев очень эффективно). (см. [например, здесь](http://baron.su/archives/194-Proizvoditelnost_mysql,_zadanie_query_plan.html))

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5886c/2

Comment: @Fangog, ну я, например, вижу, что индекс применяется. У вас по-другому?

Answer (score 3):

По поводу количества фильтруемых записей, действительно, задумываться нужен ли индекс в данном случае следует особо. Т.к. условия на неравенство (Not equal) могут приводить к тому, что индексы не будут использоваться вовсе, даже без вычисления необходимости использования ключей при построении плана. Типа если `<>`, тогда table scan и поехали.
Тем временем, если таких записей будет действительно много, в процентном отношении, то индекс может оказаться более предпочтительным, а mysql его даже в расчет брать не будет.

Если на реальных данных нет использования индекса, сравните производительность с запросом

```
...FROM `users` FORCE INDEX(rang_users)...
```

Если он будет быстрее, значит надо пересобрать статистику по таблице (неплохо это делать периодически).

```
ANALYZE TABLE users
```

И возможно индекс появится в плане. Если mysql будет попрежнему настаивать, можно сначала подсказать ему

```
...FROM `users` USE INDEX(rang_users)...
```

и если и это не поможет, тогда `FORCE`.
И стоит вообще избегать(по возможности конечно) ситуаций когда понадобятся not equal сравнения.
[Хорошая статья](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index) про индексы и mysql, который не всегда прав.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `mytable` 
WHERE NOT number =  '23'
```

выберет все кроме колонки с содержанием '23'.

если надо выбирать по строке то:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `string_column` NOT like "%часть строки%"
```

выберет все записи кроме тех записей, в строке которых содержится "часть строки".